# Missing Plug-in error while placing dashboard web clip widget on the desktop

Tags: safari, command-line, high-sierra, plugins, dashboard-widget

Hi before updating my macOS to 10.13.6 I was able to use the next command:

> `defaults write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES`

to **drag my safari web clip widgets from Dashboard to my desktop**, but after I updated the OS version to High Sierra I face the error after a widget is placed on the desktop doesn't appear and I see the **error** right in the center of the **empty widget** which had been placed on the desktop:

> Missing Plug-in

despite the dashboard widgets such as Clock and Calendar display on the desktop perfectly.

I googled about it but found nothing and can't guess what's wrong.
But I found that this feature of placing widgets from Dashboard to desktop works well with the same OS version which I use (High Sierra, 10.13.6.).
I guess something wrong with my OS / Safari.
I can't update my OS right now so I would be appreciated for advice about how to fix this without updating my OS to the latest.
Safari version: 13.0.3 (no updates available in AppStore for my OS version.

What I tried which did not help:

```
write com.apple.dashboard devmode NO
write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES
killall Dock
reboot
```

One of the web clips in the Dashboard is very important for me so I'd like to see it on my desktop again.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: May OS reinstalling with the same version help? Thanks.

Comment: I found the same problem here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250676276 and suddenly after killing the Dashboard process I found the web clip on the desktop has worked! I added killing command of both Dashboard and Dock in my cron jobs in order to renew the info in the webclip as well as to fix Missing Plug-in error. Now my question is if there's a way to go without this crutch? Thanks.

Comment: Unite app for macOS did what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a technique I've found that fixes this issue, at least on a couple of my macOS 10.14 systems:

1. Open System Preferences and pick Mission Control
2. Change the Dashboard setting to "Off"
3. Open a terminal window and execute the following to restart the Dock:
   `launchctl stop com.apple.Dock.agent`
   ...if the Dock doesn't relaunch, also execute:
   `launchctl start com.apple.Dock.agent`
4. Change the Dashboard setting back to "As Overlay" or "As Space"

Hopefully your web clips are working again! No need to blow away preferences and set everything up again.

edit: While this did work for me a few times, it has now failed to work today. So your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks, but I updated to Monterey and found Unite app that made all (!) that I needed!